# Delete one slide from a Google Presentation using API based off of date

Tags: google-slides-api, google-slides

Is it even possible to have a slide presentation delete a slide base off of a date. For example have the slide expire after a certain date. The purpose is for digital signage. I was just hoping to write a script that deleted a slide.

Please let me know if my question is not clear.

## first post #not a programmer...yet

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to do a cron. Cron is time-based job scheduler, to run periodically at fixed times, dates, or intervals.

One sample would be using a time-driven trigger to run a function (delete slide).

The code snippet that I used would be in Apps Script to run using a time driven trigger and code to delete a page in a slide.

```
function checkslide(){

  var origin = Slides.Presentations.get(originSlideID).slides;

  Logger.log(origin[1])
  var slide  = SlidesApp.openById(targetSlideID).getSlides();

  //remove all slide other than first page
  slide.splice(targetSlideID - 1, 1);
  for (var i in slide) {
    slide[i].remove();
  }

  //remove a specify depending on condition where j is the slide to be removed

  for (i = 0; i < slide.length; i++) {
    if(i == j){
      slide[i].remove();
    }

  }

}
```

References:

https://developers.google.com/slides/samples/writing#delete_a_page_or_page_element
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable